# TCP/TLS sockets in helidon

Tags: helidon

Can we use Helidon framework to build a service which can accept TCP/TLS connections from remote server ?

Trying to explore helidon framework to see if it exposes a raw tcp socket on a newly built microservice.

By raw tcp socket I mean that new microservice shall expose a socket where it shall be able to receive proprietary messages over tcp packet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at Netty instead of Helidon. Helidon is built on top of Netty and offers a neat framework for developing applications running on HTTP. Take a look at WebSocket (via Tyrus) and GRPC support within Helidon.

Do not use Helidon for raw TCP-based applications. You could instead take a look at Netty which Helidon is based on. Netty offers an event loop based NIO framework and exposes inbound and outbound pipelines, where you can chain your own protocol and message handlers. The initial learning curve is steep, but it may be worth it.